# Visual studio package manager console migrations refuse to use connection string

Tags: .net, entity-framework-5, entity-framework-migrations

I run Add-Migration like so

```
PM> Add-Migration -ConnectionStringName "ViducationConnection" -Verbose -StartUpProjectName "Viducate.Domain"
```

And this is what I get:

```
cmdlet Add-Migration at command pipeline position 1
Supply values for the following parameters:
Name: myoj
Using StartUp project 'Viducate.Domain'.
Using NuGet project 'Viducate.Domain'.
System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> System.Data.ProviderIncompatibleException: An error occurred while getting provider information from the database. This can be caused by Entity Framework using an incorrect connection string. Check the inner exceptions for details and ensure that the connection string is correct. ---> System.Data.ProviderIncompatibleException: The provider did not return a ProviderManifestToken string. ---> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified)
```

Now the weird thing here is that if I run the project it works, I have checked the connection string, it works (also not changed).
This has worked before just like this with nothing changed connection-wise

No matter what name I give the connection string it fails the same, I can give it the correct name or "whatever" it fails exactly the same way.
Making me think it does not find the connection string.

But it's there, both in my web.config in main project as well as app.config in the Vidcate.Domain project.

And this has worked before. However I got this very problem one other time, but that time once I had browsed the sql server (azure btw) from the visual studio sql server object explorer it worked that time. No such luck this time. I have tried rebooting, turning off firewall etc. no luck.

Less than ideal we are two developers working with same db so sometimes one updates it and a mismatch is created but still it should not fail to connect in this way so it should not matter.

Edit: my connection string is:

```
<add name="ViducationConnection" connectionString="Server=tcp:v6u2f4fbbg.database.windows.net,1433;Database=vidutesAqx321gza;User ID=myuser@v6u2f4fbbg;Password=mypassword;Trusted_Connection=False;Encrypt=True;Connection Timeout=30;MultipleActiveResultSets=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

Comment: Have you enabled your IP to access Azure database? I suspect that is the problem

Comment: Yes I have, and I just double checked that my ip has not changed. I should mention that I can use SQL Server Management studio AND Visual studio SQL Server Object Explorer AND I can take the exact connection string and feed it into ConnMaker.exe from microsoft and it works. So this is only from Package Manager Console

Comment: I should also mention that this have worked before. I did get this error once, and then it just randomly disappear.

Answer (score 0):

Okay so it seems that overnight my visual simply decided to stop listening to -ConnectionStringName

Because when I go into the app.config and add the exact same connection string but with the name of my dbcontext it worked right away.

so using custom connection string, simply stopped working.

Comment: But then again when i try to update localdb (used for unit tests) it does listen to ConnectionStringName. This is so odd indeed. but at least it works now.